# Для чего нужен ряд свойств OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot, графики

А именно:

- double LabelMargin
- double MinimumSegmentLength
- Все свойства связанные с BrokenLine:

  - double BrokenLineThickness
  - LineStyle BrokenLineStyle
  - OxyColor BrokenLineColor

Менял их, никакого результата. И на сайте OxyPlot никакой информации нет.

Answer (score 0):

С их помощью настраиваются разрывы.
На примере линейного графика, разрывы появляются, где стоит значение float.NaN

[image: Серый цвет - разрыв]